# How can I test my function before storing my input into a database or json file?

Tags: python, function

Perhaps someone here can help me. I am trying to create a habit-tracking app as a project and I have created a habit class along with a habit creation function that I defined. Eventually, I want to be able to use a sqlite database to hold my data. I have not coded the database functionality yet, but I wanted to test my function to at least see if the logic works. Until now, this is what I have:

```
from datetime import date
class Habit: 
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, description: str):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        
    def initiate_habit(self): 
        habit_name = input('Enter a habit name: ')
        type = input('Enter a habit type: ')
        duration = input("Enter habit duration (daily, weekly, monthly): ")
        start_date = date.today()
        end_date = input('Enter end date: ')
```

When I try to call my function, I get the following error:
NameError: name 'initiate_habit' is not defined
Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

To test:

```
habit = Habit('Read', 'Read 15 pages daily')
initiate_habit()
```

When I try running my initiate_habit function, I receive the below-mentioned error:

> NameError: name 'initiate_habit' is not defined
> `

Comment: Your line is invalid, either is misses a dot before the method name, or a new line (which would raises your error))

Comment: Also, since `initiate_habit()` is a method of `Habit` class, you have to specify `habit.initiate_habit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method, is an instance method, how could the code know `initiate_habit` is related to `habit` if you don't tell it

Shoule be

```
habit = Habit('Read', 'Read 15 pages daily')
habit.initiate_habit()
```

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I forgot to add the habit.initiate_habit()...once I did, I could run through the sequence.

Comment: @B.Copeland You can now think about accepting the answer, the green tick on the left ;)

Comment: The answer has been checked. Thanks again for your assistance.